# String or Char between range without RegEx (Switch)

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Is there any other option to identify if a char is a letter or number without using RegEx?
Here's my code:

```
void IdentifyChar(char Chr)
{
    switch (Chr)
    {
        case // A..Z or A-Z
    }
}
```

I know it is possible because some time ago I downloaded a project with this code, and it worked.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't support *range-based* cases inside a *switch*, though there are several other alternatives to use besides your current goal.

A few approaches is described below.

```
 if (Char.ToLower (Chr) >= 'a' && Char.ToLower (Chr) <= 'z') {
   ...

 } else
 if (Chr >= '0' && Chr <= '9') {
   ...

 } else {
   ...
 }
```

```
 if (Char.IsLetter (Chr)) {
    ...

 } else
 if (Char.IsDigit (Chr)) {
    ...

 } else
 {
   ...
 }
```

---

You can find many more methods (and the associated info) to find out in what `category` a certain character resides by following this link below:

- **[msdn.microsoft.com - Char Structure (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)**

---

<sup>**not recommended:** There is sort of a *"range-based"* method of using a switch, but it doesn't involve you specifying a range but all the values associated with a certain case, such as in the below:</sup>

```
switch (Chr) {
  case '0':
  case '1':
  case '2':
  case '3':
  case '4':
  case '5':
  case '6':
  case '7':
  case '8':
  case '9':
    ... 
    break;

  default:
    ...
}
```

---

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Char.IsLetterOrDigit(Chr)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424s1h3z for other `Char Methods`

Comment: That may not be what he wants. The question coffee is ambiguous if he's trying to act only on letters.

Comment: @MikeBantegui maybe but this is what i understand from `Is there any other option to identify if a char is a letter or number`